# Does "There is a new answer" pop up too early?

Tags: discussion

I just had this scenario: a question where an impulse answer came to mind. Posted that but for sure it was not good enough. However, there's a 5-minute grace period where edits can be done without having a revision. But obviously the `There is a new answer` has popped up already and someone read and down-voted.

Now my question: should that message only appear after the grace period? That would as well mean that answers will pop up earliest 5 minutes after a question has been asked. For me as an answerer that would be ok since often I proof read only after submitting (and I've seen many `An edit as been made` while watching).

Comment: Folks have always been able to see new answers during the grace period; "there is a new answer" is merely additional notification.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guesses so. My question stands, if the post should only be available after the grace period has passed.

Comment: it is a trademark of Stack Exchange system that questions can be answered in a few seconds and system is purposely designed so that after one hits the answer button lots of things happen and lots of people get notified, asker, folks typing their answers, readers of the question, users watching "active" tab. There were lots of suggestions to change this (see eg [here and linked posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6917/165773 "Don't show the answers for the question in the first 2 minutes")) but none succeeded so far: it is unlikely that such a core feature will change

Comment: @gnat That answers my question :-)

Comment: There is a work around for not having this feature.  The preview.  You get to see how you're question will actually look in all it's glory before anyone see's it for as long as you want.  I've used this to sit on and refine a question for days before anyone see's it.  Wish more people knew they could do that.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I know about the Preview and it's fine. But me (and I've seen others) often submit to see the answer in the context of the page. So basically I see that I should not submit unless I really have written everything. I'd prefer it the other way round, but that will not happen for explained reasons.

Comment: @ThomasKilian and that's why you're allowed to delete, edit, and then undelete.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Yes, I sometimes fall back to that.

Comment: *"I should not submit unless I really have written everything"* - no, that is not necessary. Just give an answer which contains enough information in a reasonable quality you don't expect to get downvotes for it. Then you can refine and add further information as you wish.

Comment: @DocBrown That was basically my issue. I was answering impulsive. And I will likely not cure my attitude to do so.